# How to "override" some of the resource parameters when using terraform modules?

Tags: terraform

i am trying to develop generic terraform modules to support data-dog monitors and let the user of the modules to append resources and/or override resources in side generic modules.

terraform [overrides](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/override.html) feature works fine without modules, But not working when using modules.

how to override some of the resource parameters inside modules?

**Requirements:**

1. */modules/datadog/monitors.tf* contains list of resources, each resource represents a generic datadog monitor with default parameter values. Each **individual application may choose to override one or more parameters inside each resource**.
2. */application-1/monitors.tf* contains module with source as **/modules/datadog/** , some more monitors that are not covered in generic monitors and some variables.

/application-1/monitors.tf

```
module "datadog" {
  source  = "/modules/datadog/"
}
```

/modules/datadog/monitors.tf

```
# Generic Datadog monitor to monitor cpu 
resource "datadog_monitor" "foo" {
  name               = "Name for monitor foo"
  type               = "metric alert"
  message            = "Monitor triggered. Notify: @hipchat-channel"
  escalation_message = "Escalation message @pagerduty"

  query = "avg(last_1h):avg:aws.ec2.cpu{environment:foo,host:foo} by {host} > 4"

  thresholds {
    ok                = 0
    warning           = 2
    warning_recovery  = 1
    critical          = 4
    critical_recovery = 3
  }

  notify_no_data    = false
  renotify_interval = 60

  notify_audit = false
  timeout_h    = 60
  include_tags = true

  silenced {
    "*" = 0
  }

  tags = ["foo:bar", "baz"]
}
```

**Solution 1**: Add overrides.tf to **/modules/datadog** Directory. terraform [override feature](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/override.html) merges content in overrides.tf to 
 configuration defined in monitors.tf.
 But the problem with this solution is each application specific overrides.tf needs to be copied over to /modules/datadog Directory before running apply command.

overrides.tf

```
resource "datadog_monitor" "foo" {
      escalation_message = "Escalation message @pagerduty1"

      thresholds {
        ok                = 0
        warning           = 20
        warning_recovery  = 10
        critical          = 40
        critical_recovery = 35
      }

      notify_no_data    = false

    }
```

**Solution 2**: can i use overrides with modules? i tried to override resource parameters by copying overrides.tf to /application-1/ Directory, But terraform is not overriding resources, instead it is considering both as different resources.

Comment: BTW i am familiar with module variables, but i am trying to find how to override resource

Comment: While your question format is okay for StackOverflow (you actually ask a question that I don't think off the top of my head has been asked before [I watch Terraform]), I do have to say that this is literally the first Google result: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/override.html –Did you try reading that?

Comment: @ChaimEliyah Thanks for your response! i explored terraform overrides terraform.io/docs/configuration/override.html, it works with out modules.  But i am trying to take advantage of both terraform overrides and modules. Specifically, i would like to override one or more parameters of resource defined in a module.

Comment: I am reasonably certain that the resources in imported modules are immutable. You would have to define a new resource, and then use the "count" flag based on a condition as specified in @Tim Theratt's answer to switch between the two.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a conditional with count to override if a resource is to be created. The example below will only create the resource when the variable environment is not = production. If Count = 0 then the resource won't be created,

Regards,

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "web_server_nsg_rule_rdp" {
  name                        = "RDP Inbound"
  priority                    = 100
  direction                   = "Inbound"
  access                      = "Allow"
  protocol                    = "Tcp"
  source_port_range           = "*"
  destination_port_range      = "3389"
  source_address_prefix       = "*"
  destination_address_prefix  = "*"
  resource_group_name         = "${azurerm_resource_group.web_server_rg.name}"
  network_security_group_name = "${azurerm_network_security_group.web_server_nsg.name}"
  count                       = "${var.environment == "production" ? 0 : 1}"  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for the solution to create resources conditionally.
i'm trying find if it is possible to override some of resource's parameters when using terraform modules.

example: adding example in the question